# SQL with having statement now want complete rows

Tags: sql, sql-server

Here is a mock table

```
MYTABLE ROWS
PKEY    1,2,3,4,5,6
COL1    a,b,b,c,d,d
COL2    55,44,33,88,22,33
```

I want to know which rows have duplicated COL1 values:

```
select col1, count(*)  
from MYTABLE
group by col1
having count(*) > 1
```

This returns :

```
b,2
d,2
```

I now want all the rows that contain b and d. Normally, I would use *where in* stmt, but with the count column, not certain what type of statement I should use?

Comment: Please, give columns as columns, not as rows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lots of ways to solve this here's another

```
select * from MYTABLE
join
(
select col1 ,count(*)
from MYTABLE
group by col1
having count(*) > 1
) s on s.col1 = mytable.col1;
```

Comment: This is what I was attempting to remember.

Answer (score 1):

maybe you need

```
select * from MYTABLE
where col1 in 
(
select col1 
from MYTABLE
group by col1
having count(*) > 1
)
```

Comment: i think , using  count(col1) is better choice then count(*) in terms of faster execution

Comment: @zeeshan12396 This is a common misconception but, no, SQL Server doesn't care what's inside `COUNT()` in terms of performance. If you pick the wrong column though (say, a nullable one), you could get wrong results.

Answer (score 1):

Use a CTE and a windowed aggregate:

```sql
WITH CTE AS(
    SELECT Pkey,
           Col1,
           Col2,
           COUNT(1) OVER (PARTITION BY Col1) AS C
    FROM dbo.YourTable)
SELECT PKey,
       Col1,
       Col2
FROM CTE
WHERE C > 1;
```